# Trying to 'stamp' an arbitrary assortment of pixels to a texture2d that may be rotated at an arbitrary angle

Tags: unity, 2d, mathematics, textures, rotation

This one is hard to explain but I'll try to not to overcomplicate it. Engine is Unity, for reference.

I have a system where an object has a 2d texture to display a custom splat map. The user can 'paint' to this texture, which uses world space coordinates of the mouse to see which pixel should be painted to. They can also paint larger shapes, which are essentially just implementations of square / circle drawing algorithms that choose what pixel coordinates to paint to based off the starting world space coordinates.

This works fine while the object/texture are unrotated, but if I rotate the object an arbitrary amount of degrees (say, 45 for the most extreme result), like squares and circle etc are drawn to the texture with missing pixels. I assume this is because the 'grid' of the texture is now rotated, and because I'm still trying to 'stamp' the shape in the original world space orientation (without respect to the rotation), the pixel 'sizes' or coordinates aren't the same?

I can't post screenshots as I'm at work, but this is what my **desired** output would be (Ignore the pixelisation, had to use an online crappy paint program), where the first square is the object in its original rotation, with a red square stamped on to it as expected. The second square is after the object is rotated 45 degrees, and the yellow square stamped on it is what I want (and what is currently appearing with missing pixels in my implementation).

[image: Desired output example]

EDIT: And here is the actual result I'm getting, pixels per unit is 16. The first square was stamped, the rect then rotated 135 degrees, and then the second square was stamped (shown with the missing pixels):
[image]

Anyone have any idea how I would go about drawing onto a rotated texture like this without ending up with missing pixels? I can post code snippets / build images later.

EDIT:

This is the code executed on the object to register a single pixel draw (very loosely), which uses the `RotatePointAroundPivot` function to get the pixel on the original pixel grid location in world space by rotating the point against the transforms current rotation. This works perfectly for individual pixel draws from mouse position clicks, but with the larger shapes I end up with the issue described

```
void DrawToTex(Vector2 worldPos) {
    worldPos = RotatePointAroundPivot(worldPos, transform.position, transform.rotation.eulerAngles)

    (xPixelCoordinate, yPixelCoordinate) = GetPixelCoordinatesFromWorldPos(worldPos);
    
    pixels[xPixelCoordinate, yPixelCoordinate] = color;
}


public Vector3 RotatePointAroundPivot(Vector3 point, Vector3 pivot, Vector3 angles) {
    return Quaternion.Euler(angles) * (point - pivot) + pivot;
}

public void DrawSquare(Vector2 worldPos, int size) {

    (int startXCoord, int startYCoord) = GetPixelCoordinatesFromWorldPos(worldPos);

    // Literally just gets an array of the correct size
    int[,] squareMatrix = GetSquareMatrix(size);

    sizeHalved = size / 2;

    pixelWorldSize = 1f / pixelsPerUnit; // pixels per unit is 16 in my build

    for(int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < size; x++) {
            int newX = startXCoord - sizeHalved + x;
            int newY = startYCoord - sizeHalved + y;

            Vector2 pixelWorldPositionToDraw = worldPos + new Vector2((newX - startXCoord) * pixelWorldSize, (newY - startYCoord) * pixelWorldSize);
            DrawToTex(pixelWorldPositionToDraw);
        }
    }
}

(int, int) GetPixelCoordinatesFromWorldPos(Vector2 worldPos) {
    float xMin = bounds.min.x;
    float yMin = bounds.min.y;
    float distFromStartX = worldPos.x - xMin;
    float distFromStartY = worldPos.y - yMin;
    float xScaled = distFromStartX * pixelsPerUnit;
    float yScaled = distFromStartY * pixelsPerUnit;
    int xPixelCoordinate = (int) xScaled;
    int yPixelCoordinate = (int) yScaled;

    return (xPixelCoordinate, yPixelCoordinate);
}
```

Comment: Normally I'd handle this by drawing the square or circle on a quad that's rendered by a camera onto the texture as a render target. This will handle all orientations because the camera/vertex shader takes care of the transformation. It sounds like you're doing this a different way though, possibly using very slow CPU-side methods like GetPixels/SetPixels? Want to show us your code so we can understand where this error is coming from?

Comment: @DMGregory Yeah I'm directly modifying the pixels using Texture2D.GetRawTextureData and modifying the native array of values & then applying.  I can supply pseudo code for now but unfortunately I won't have access to my project until the end of the day when I get home:

Comment: @DMGregory have updated the original post with the pseudo code for how I use the world position to register pixels to draw

Comment: If you are drawing square with this direct method, you have to have `for` loop at some point, right? Can you show it? Anyways my suspicion is that lost pixel are cased by rounding errors, because you are doing so many calculations for each call. Try calculate bounding points once and then do loops in texture coordinates, Or may be there is just resolution mismatch — there is not enough worldspace pixels to cover all texturespace pixels. It's hard to judge without seeing actual results.

Comment: @ShadowsInRain updated post with pseudo code for the function that loops / calls for the drawing to the texture. Still at work so don't have access to the exact code, but thats the gist

Comment: Added a result picture now I have access to my build